# Merge data in a table into one cell

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I try to load a table from database and I want to merge data in each column into separate cells. This is following table:

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cell a1 | Cell b1 | Cell c1 | Cell d1 |
| NULL | Cell b2 | Cell c2 | NULL |
| NULL | NULL | Cell c3 | NULL |

And this is **output required**

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cell a1 | Cell b1 Cell b2 | Cell c1 Cell c2 Cell c3 | Cell d1 |

This is my code to load table in file VB:

```
Private Sub LOAD_TABLE (ByVal iID As Integer)
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("LOAD_TB")
    Dim s As String = ""
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = iID
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@T", SqlDbType.Int).Value = DrListT.SelectedValue
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@N", SqlDbType.Int).Value = DrListN.SelectedValue

    Using con As New SqlConnection(Class_pub.conString)
        Using sda As New SqlDataAdapter()
            cmd.Connection = con
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd
            Using dt As New DataTable
                sda.Fill(dt)
                GRV_H.DataSource = dt
                GRV_H.DataBind()
            End Using
        End Using

        If con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            con.Close()
            con.Dispose()
        End If
    End Using
End Sub
```

And the code to display table in file ASPX:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GRV_H" DataKeyNames="ID" AutoGenerateColumns="False" runat="server"
    AllowPaging="False" Width="100%">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#FCFCFC" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <input id="id1" type="text" name="txt1" style="width: 80px; font-family: Arial"
                    class="textbox_numeric" value='<%# Eval("ColumnA", "{0:#,##0}") %>' onkeyup="this.value=FormatNumber(this.value);"
                     onclick="return this.focus();" onfocus="this.select();"
                    autocomplete="Off" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <HeaderTemplate>
                Column A</HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="60px" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <input id="id2" type="text" name="txt2" style="width: 80px; font-family: Arial"
                    class="textbox_numeric" value='<%# Eval("ColumnB", "{0:#,##0}") %>' onkeyup="this.value=FormatNumber(this.value);"
                     onclick="return this.focus();" onfocus="this.select();"
                    autocomplete="Off" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <HeaderTemplate>
                Column B</HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="60px" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <input id="id3" type="text" name="txt3" style="width: 75px; font-family: Arial"
                    class="textbox_numeric" value='<%# Eval("ColumnC", "{0:#,##0}") %>' readonly="readonly" onclick="return this.focus();" onfocus="this.select();"
                    autocomplete="Off" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <HeaderTemplate>
                Column C</HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="75px" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <input id="id4" type="text" name="txt4" style="width: 60px; font-family: Arial"
                    class="textbox_numeric" value='<%# Eval("ColumnD", "{0:#,##0}") %>' onkeyup="this.value=FormatNumber(this.value);"
                    onchange="" onclick="return this.focus();" onfocus="this.select();" autocomplete="Off"
                    runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <HeaderTemplate>
                Column D</HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="60px" />
        </asp:TemplateField>                             
    </Columns>
    <HeaderStyle CssClass="style_header_Grid" />
    <RowStyle CssClass="style_item_Grid" />
    <PagerStyle CssClass="style_header_Grid" Font-Bold="true" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the way to "apporach" this logic and problem?

Process data at the table level in code, and NOT from the gridview (which is for display of data.

So Logic:

Load the data into a table.

Create a 2nd table, and process above rows into ONE row in this 2nd table.

Send 2nd table to GridView.

So, say this markup

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Load Grid" CssClass="btn"
    OnClick="Button1_Click"
    />
<br />
<br />

<h3>Original table data</h3>
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="table"
    Width="30%" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName"/>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="City"/>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName"/>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

<br />
<h3>Crunched table data</h3>

<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" CssClass="table"
    Width="30%" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HtmlEncode="False" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HtmlEncode="False" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HtmlEncode="False" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

And code to load and process would be this:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim strSQL As String =
        "SELECT LastName, City, HotelName FROM tblHotels
        WHERE ID IN (127, 120, 124)"

    Using conn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST4)
        Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL, conn)

            Dim rstSource As New DataTable
            Dim rstCrunched As New DataTable

            conn.Open()

            rstSource.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)

            GridView1.DataSource = rstSource    ' show origional data
            GridView1.DataBind()

            For Each MyColumn In rstSource.Columns
                rstCrunched.Columns.Add(MyColumn.ColumnName)
            Next

            Dim ResultRow As DataRow = rstCrunched.NewRow
            For Each OneRow As DataRow In rstSource.Rows
                For Each MyColumn As DataColumn In rstSource.Columns
                    If ResultRow(MyColumn.ColumnName).ToString <> "" Then
                        ResultRow(MyColumn.ColumnName) &= "<br/>"
                    End If
                    ResultRow(MyColumn.ColumnName) &= OneRow(MyColumn.ColumnName)
                Next

            Next
            rstCrunched.Rows.Add(ResultRow)
            GridView2.DataSource = rstCrunched    ' show crunched data
            GridView2.DataBind()

        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

And result is this when button clicked

[image]

However, there is a LOT of issues here.

If you using bound fields, then above HtmlEncode="False" is required.

however, if you using lables, (in templated column), then again above is fine.

If you using text boxes, then this:

```
 ResultRow(MyColumn.ColumnName) &= vbCrLf
```

So, either way, pre-processing of the data is quite much the road to take.

Comment: Sir, I use TemplateField and Boundfield, and TemplateField has input tag, should I use ResultRow(MyColumn.ColumnName) &= vbCrLf ?

Comment: If using a bound field, then add HtmlEncode="False"  and use <br/>. This will also work for a templated control and label. However, for a templated text box, you use vbcrlf. TextBox does not render standard html in the text, but a label does, and a boundfield will with Htmlencode="False".  So, really only different case is a textbox.

Comment: I use vbCrLf and add HtmlEncode at Boundfield, but got an error Public member 'ColumnName' on type 'TemplateField' not found at rstCrunched.Columns.Add(MyColumn.ColumnName). Did I miss something ?

Comment: Hum, what is the value of column name? (break-point it, or add a debug.print(MyColumn.ColumnName). I don't think spaces matter in the column name, but check what the column name is.